# Sequence of funtions $f_n = n(f(x+ \frac{1}{n})-f(x))$ for the continous differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Let  $f$ be a continous differentiable function on $\mathbb R$. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions $f_n = n(f(x+ \frac{1}{n})-f(x))$. Then

(a) $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$

(b) $f_n$ converges on $\mathbb R$, but not necessarily uniformly.

(c) $f_n$ converges to the derivative of $f$ uniformly on$[0,1]$

(d) there is no guarantee that $f_n$ converges on any open interval.

We know that $f'(x) =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n}) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. Thus $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f'$

Please tell me how to check the uniform convergence. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: You can write $f_n$ in the form
$$f_n(x)=\int_0^1 f'\left(x+{\tau\over n}\right)\>d\tau\ .$$

Comment: definitely Sir $f$ can be written in the form and $|f_n(x)| \leq \int_0^1 |f'(x + \frac{\tau}{n})| d\tau \leq M_n$ .  I also want little bit help for finding $M_n$ to find in whcih interval $M_n$ convergent to $0$. Thanks for yur prompt reply.