# Uniform convergence of the function sequence $f_n(x)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

I'm new to uniform converge in sequence function, so I have:

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous differentiable function in $R$.

$f_n(x)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$.

I need to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ and to prove that for any interval $[a, b], f_n(x)$ converge uniformly.

Now, is that correct that: for every $x$ in $R$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))=0$
therefore the sequence function converge to zero. In addition, $f'(x) =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n}) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0$ so for every $x$, so we have a constant function and therefore converge uniformly. Can you help me with this? Thanks!!

Comment: I thought it should be that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f'(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand what to you mean....

Comment: How did you get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))=0$?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ is not correct. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f'(x)$ as you have found out in your calculation.

Comment: This question seems to be closely related: [Sequence of funtions $f_n = n(f(x+ \frac{1}{n})-f(x))$ for the continous differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780734/sequence-of-funtions-f-n-nfx-frac1n-fx-for-the-continous-differe)